# Flutter Firebase Storage video gets rotated

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm not sure this is `flutter` or `Firebase Storage`. 
I captured video with my iPhone portrait mode and uploaded to `Firebase Storage`. When I play that video, it gets rotated. So it looks wired like video is stretched to the screen. I guess it looks ok if you see it in landscape mode but since I disable my app to rotate, there is no way to see it correct aspect ratio.
I upload video and play it like so.

```
Future _upload(File file) async {
  try {
      String now = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
      String storageId = (now + uid);
      String contentType = 'video/mp4';
      StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("video").child(storageId);
      StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(file, StorageMetadata(contentType: contentType));

      Uri downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;
      String url = downloadUrl.toString();
      print(url);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }



VideoPlayerController _controller;


new AspectRatio(
   aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
   child: new VideoPlayer(_controller)
 )
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What if you change your aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,  to aspectRatio: size.width / size.height,

Comment: Thank for your comment! I tried your aspect ratio but looked the same. I tried height/width then became correct aspect ratio. But the point is I don’t want it to be rotated. If you capture with portrait mode then I want it to be portrait. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be this known issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17606
with a pending pull request https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17606#issuecomment-415621941

Please upvote the issue to increase priority.